# my attribute value is coming html tag how to parse the value in android

Tags: android

my attribute value is coming in html tag .can any body tell how to parse the value

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you having multiple Attribute String values and just want to display it on screen, there is no need to parse, just display them using  [**`WebView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) .

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```